# Swift Generics Cannot convert return expression

Tags: swift, generics, types

I have a protocol like so:

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype Entity: EntityType

    func getAll() throws -> [Entity]
}
```

and a generic type conforming to Repository:

```
class AnyRepository<Entity:EntityType>: Repository {
    public init<ConcreteRepository: Repository>(_ repository: ConcreteRepository) where ConcreteRepository.Entity == Entity {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to map an Entity name to their respective repositories like so

```
class Saver<Entity: EntityType> {

    var repository: AnyRepository<Entity> {
        if User.name == Entity.name {
            return AnyRepository(UserRepository())
        }
    }

}
```

However I'm getting the error 'Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyRepository' (aka 'AnyRepository') to return type'

User is an Entity type just like the generic parameter of the Saver class

Any ideas, any help would be appreciated? Thanks in advance

Comment: Right, `Entity` is a generic parameter, which means it can be any type different from `User`. Imagine you have a class `Vehicle` that also conforms to `EntityType`. Then `Saver<Vehicle>().repository` will expect `AnyRepository<Vehicle>` to be returned, while your code always returns `AnyRepository<User>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the idea is that the repository var could return any type of Repository the code always returns a User repository right now but could return a Product repository or a Vehicle repository

Answer (score 1):

This can't work safely, because now when you call the function like this:

```
Saver<Car>().repository
```

you'd get back an `AnyRepository<Car>`, but the actual type would be `AnyRepository<User>` so whenever you'd call some method specific to `Car` it wouldn't find that on the `User` class and throw an error, that's why this is disallowed.